# Count rows with specific property

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have the following table:

[image]

I only want to count each rows which look like that: `K,0,1`

I tried

`=AND(COUNTIF(A:A;"K");COUNTIF(B:B;0);COUNTIF(C:C;1))`

However that only gives me a boolean value back and does not count?

I really appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: try `=COUNTIFs(A:A;"K";B:B;0;C:C;1)`

Comment: @simoco Please add your answer below so that I can accept it!

Comment: user2051347, accept AmitShakya's answer:)

Comment: Thanks simoco. I have added your name in answer that i have written. Because you have given it first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIFS` extends the usefulness of the `COUNTIF` function by allowing you to specify from 2 to 127 criteria rather than just one as in COUNTIF.

`COUNTIFs(A:A;"K";B:B;0;C:C;1)` It should work fine. And solution is already stated by `simoco` via comment.

Let me know, if it works.